# Is it possible to search for a graphical symbol in an image using Photoshop?

Tags: drawing, photoshop, autocad, photoshop-script, autocad-plugin

Is there a way to search for a specific symbol in an image the same way you would search for a piece of text in a word document?

For example, say you have a set of plans, and you need to find all instances of a symbol and you don't know how many there are. In the attached example I am looking for all the items highlighted in pink, green and blue (highlighting was added by me). enter image description here

I have searched Youtube and Google but couldn't find any answers - maybe I am not capable of phrasing my query properly. Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Photoshop can't do that, you'll probably want to write/find something based on openCV...

Comment: The only way Photoshop could do that would be to split the image up into components and then detect each image by having a unique size. That's two big IFs. Photoshop is not your friend here. Using openCV and Python would be a much better way of doing this